# JS/CSS: Animating a circle expanding out from another circle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get a circle to expand from itself, while keeping the original circle. What I want is something like when you hover over the circles (e.g. water) on [this page](https://yourplanyourplanet.sustainability.google) (click lets get started to see the circles). I'm not sure how to do this. Note that my knowledge of jQuery is quite small, so if you find a way to do this with jQuery, can you try to keep it simple? Thanks in advance. The earlier the better, as this is for a school project.

I tried to make the div have a function for onmouseover, but then I don't know how to get the rest. I was thinking about while the div animates from a smaller width and height, to move the circle, but the circle will still expand from the middle, and not the old circle.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site isn't a free coding or homework completing service. We're not going to do the work for you. Please read through the docs in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for information about what is considered on-topic for the site before posting again.

Comment: Try coding a solution yourself, then if you are having trouble, post your code and we can help you.

Comment: I did do a coding solution, it's just that I know my method was completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a CSS-only setup, then see if you actually need Javascript at all. This will generally always be more responsive/faster-loading. However, if you're already loading a JS library and it has functions built for this (like jQuery), then sure make use of them. There are plenty of tutorials for animating elements, CSS or JS.

Play around with numbers and styling as you wish.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/ZwPMvM)

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:before {
 content: "";
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.circle:hover:before {
  transform: scale(1.7) translate(-20%,-30%);
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="circle red">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry. Forgot. I did it now.